# Connect Docker oracle EE + sqlplus

Tags: oracle, docker, sqlplus, oracle12c

I am trying to connect the [official sqlplus](https://store.docker.com/profiles/own3dh2so4/content/sub-f73dd024-50b7-484d-88bf-2ae77e544820) docker container to the [official  Oracle Database EE](https://store.docker.com/images/oracle-database-enterprise-edition/plans/08cf8677-bb8f-453c-b667-6b0c24a388d4?tab=instructions)

First I start the Oracle Database EE container:

```
  $docker run -d -it --name OracleEE -P store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1
  $docker port OracleEE 
     1521/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32773
     5500/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32772
  $docker inspect OracleEE | grep -i IPAddress
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

Now, ¿How can I connect to this database?

In the docker image doc I read:

> You can run a container interactively to execute ad-hoc SQL and PL/SQL statements in SQL*Plus:
>
> docker run -ti --rm store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1 sqlplus hr/welcome@example.com/pdborcl

For this reason I understood that this command must work:

```
 $docker run -ti --rm store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1 sqlplus sys/Oradoc_db1@172.17.0.2:32773/orcl.localdomain
```

But the response is the following error:

```
  SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Sep 20 11:42:31 2017
  
  Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
  
  ERROR:
  ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
  
  
  Enter user-name:
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem. The problem is communication between containers. I need add a link

```
  docker run -it --rm --link OracleEE:db store/oracle/database-instantclient:12.2.0.1 sqlplus64 sys/Oradoc_db1@db:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain as sysdba
```

Now works fine!